Doing ajax call on toggle switch
I have a problem, with my script. its not working.
I want to do toggle switch checkbox. and then do ajax post call
When is checked do a ajax call and disable the toggle switch
When its unchecked also do a ajax call and disable the toggle switch
<form method="POST">
    <table class="table-hover mb-0 wd-100p">
        <tbody class="tx-12">
            <tr>
                <td>Betting</td>
                <td class="tx-right">
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="primary" id="toggle_1" data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Disabled" data-on="Enabled" />
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>


function callA() {
    $('#toggle_1').change(function(){
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        function Execute() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file1.php",
            data: {},
            success: function(response) {
            $("#display_response").html(response.msg);
            $("#toggle_1").attr("disabled", true);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            },
        });
    }
    };
    if ($(this).is(':checked') == false) {
        function Execute() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file2.php",
            data: {},
            success: function(response) {
            $("#display_response").html(response.msg);
            $("#toggle_1").attr("disabled", true);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            },
        });
    }
    };

    });    
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    callA();
});


Hey. Where and when are you calling function execute?

"It's not working" isn't particularly descriptive of the problem. You have explained your desired result, but what does happen when you run your code? Is there an error in the dev console? Does it do something else? Is the ajax call returning an unexpected value?

You're drastically over-complicating this.  What is even the purpose of this Execute() function that you define (in a confusing scope with potential conflicts from hoisting) and then never call?
If you just want to make an AJAX call, then make an AJAX call.  If the difference between the if and else branch is just the URL then just make the difference the URL.  Don't over-engineer things with functions and scope problems.  Simply perform the task you want to perform.
For example:
$('#toggle_1').change(function(){
  let url = '';
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    url = 'file1.php';
  } else {
    url = 'file2.php';
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {},
    success: function(response) {
      $("#display_response").html(response.msg);
      $("#toggle_1").attr("disabled", true);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error");
    },
  });
});

